Improving the load capacity of a Lack (or other) console table
I have a IKEA lack console (max load 44lbs) table I've used happily as a TV stand for a number of years. I'm looking to upgrade to a 65" TV and noticed it would exceed the weight capacity of the Lack by 20 lbs (about 10kg). I looked at some other IKEA TV stands that are tall, and most of them have a max capacity of 55lbs, which would still be short of the 58lbs or so I need.
I'm wondering if the load capacity is dictated by the particle board support members, and it i could improve the capacity by using some metal supports or brackets. Something like https://www.amazon.com/Stainless-Mending-Plate-Connectors-Furniture/dp/B0BTHGK6WH
Or is this a fools endeavor since metal frame tables are available at a comparable cost from Amazon, albeit, they look a bit worse.

On the one hand, I +1 the answer that says "get another table", because it isn't just the absolute weight concern but also the consequences if something goes wrong. But on the flip side, check the TV specs carefully - the first ones I checked were well under 55 lbs, with the shipping weight of one of them close to 65 lbs, but it is actual weight that matters, not shipping weight.

Thanks for this. I was able to double-check the spec sheet. Its a bit better than my estimate, but not by much:
Shipping Weight - 73.9 lbs
Set Weight without Stand (lb) - 50.5
Set Weight with Stand (lb) - 57.5

Sell it used, buy a different table.
IKEA is value-engineered to just about meet its specs and often turns out to be built of laminate sheets over a cardboard core where you might expect something more substantial in "normal" furniture. It makes it light, affordable, and able to do exactly what it claims, not much if any more.
If you think the metal ones look worse, go looking for some actual wooden tables. Those can be had easily in construction from delicate to dancing on the table is fine.
If you own, or rent from a reasonable landlord (check first about drilling holes in the walls, though), you might also consider a TV wall mount.

Thanks for the response. I think you are right. I might spent way too long trying to bodge particle board to do what its not supposed to! Thanks for the response!

Also my landlord isn't what you would call reasonable, so something free-standing it is :)

The Lack Console isn’t particleboard, it’s honeycomb paper (not that it really matters - the limit is what it is).

Lack coffee tables are thin ply over cardboard honeycomb, with particleboard on the back.  They're surprisingly strong. I've stood on them a good few times and I'm nearly 90kg.  When I broke one up after it suffered water damage, even jumping on the top (with the legs removed and placed flat underneath) took a few goes to break it.  So I was quite surprised to find cardboard honeycomb in there. But then honeycomb structures like that are used in some very strong light structures

@ChrisH   So they are interior doors with legs?

@crip659 pretty much. Thinner walls round the edges of course, but the honeycomb seems a bit better than in my doors

Yes you can.
The answer from @Ecnerwal provides good advice, and if you're willing to take it, just go do that.  This answer will help you if you insist on proceeding this way.  It's not impossible.
Ikea's weight limits are generic ones that assume you do the worst possible thing in the dumbest possible way.  You can usually adapt the furniture to do one specific thing safely if you do it smartly.
The piece is tall and narrow. Place it free-standing in the center of a room with a floral arrangement in a large vase weighing 55 pounds sitting in the middle.  You are within the weight limit! But disaster will soon follow.
On the other hand if you stablize the table and the object and place the weight over the legs it can probably hold a lot more.
The legs of a 65" TV will be quite near the ends of the table -- about 10 inches from each end.  The table will obviously be against a wall.
Fasten the table to the wall securely with at least 2 wall brackets.  If the included brackets employ plastic or fabric straps don't use them.  Those only prevent falling.  Use metal angle brackets.  Follow the furniture's instructions regarding where to screw the bracket to it.  With the paper honeycomb furniture, you can't guess.  There is wood structure somewhere.  Then fasten it securely to the wall so that the console is unable to sway left-to-right and so that the weight of the center of the console is partly taken by the wall.
Finally, fasten the TV to the console and/or to the wall.   Not to support its weight but to prevent it tipping.  If you fasten the TV to the console AND to the wall that will make the whole arrangement even stronger.
Yes, you'll be drilling and fastening to the wall but this is much, much easier than hanging a 65 inch TV on the wall. The wall isn't supporting much weight.  You don't need a TV bracket and you don't have to level it.  The wall is just just stabilizing the console to prevent skewing and tipping.

The wood structure in these is basically just at the top of the legs (I've broken one up). The sidewalls are as thin as the top, at least on some Lack. So to screw brackets into it, I'd glue ply onto the bottom. But you're right about the worst case. I reckon it could take the rated load long term at a point in the middle, so distributed widely it could take much more

@ChrisH actually the LACK console table instructions do not include wall bracing!  Glue relies on the peeling strength of the veneer.   Your first suggestion: Inside the leg at the top, is best.

Thank you for the detailed instruction and for mentioning that the best course of action is to probably buy a decent table. I think technically @Ecnerwal's answer is correct - but I really wanted to thank you for taking the time to respond to me. I selected that one as the "right" answer, but am up-voting yours!
